# Field injection in @HiltWorker using hilt

Tags: android, android-workmanager, dagger-hilt

I need to implement field inject in @HiltWorker but field injection returning null. Here is my worker code.

```
@HiltWorker
public class BackgroundTasks extends Worker {

@Inject
SessionManager sessionManager;


@AssistedInject
public BackgroundTasks(@Assisted @NonNull Context context, @Assisted @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
    super(context, params);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Timber.tag("TAGGGGGGG").i(sessionManager.getJwtModel().getUserName());
    return Result.success();
 }
}
```

Here is my custom work manager configuration

```
Configuration myConfig = new Configuration.Builder()
            .setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.INFO)
            .build();

WorkManager.initialize(this, myConfig);
```

Here is my manifest file where I am removing the work manager default configuration

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

I hope, it's enough information for understanding my scenario. If anyone needs, please ask.
Thanks

Comment: May I ask why you need to field inject this values as it can easily be constructor injected?

Comment: Field-injection could be useful inside a common base class of several workers. Without this feature all the ancestors need to pass the same bunch of dependencies to the constructor of the parent class (boilerplate!).

Answer (score 1):

WorkManager should be initialized by Hilt. So you should not do

```java
WorkManager.initialize(this, myConfig);
```

Instead, your Application class sets up like the following.

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application(), Configuration.Provider {

  @Inject lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

  override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
      Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}
```

As explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack).